# jenkins question - Importing library failed: OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000000 - execution runs perfectly in cmd line

Tags: java, jenkins, access-violation, oserror

14:27:52 [ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\jenkins\workspace\1_UnitRegressionTestSuites\libraries\Public_Resource.robot' on line 2: Importing library 'C:\jenkins\workspace\1_UnitRegressionTestSuites\libraries\PLCSimRBT_lib.py' failed: OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000000
14:27:52 Traceback (most recent call last):
14:27:52   File "C:\jenkins\workspace\1_UnitRegressionTestSuites\libraries\PLCSimRBT_lib.py", line 12, in 
14:27:52     PlcManager = PlcSimManager()
14:27:52   File "C:\jenkins\workspace\1_UnitRegressionTestSuites\libraries\plcsim\api\manager.py", line 46, in **init**
14:27:52     ret = self.cdll.CInitializeApi(byref(self.mgr_c_p))
14:27:52 [ ERROR ] [PLCSIM] Error initialising library: ErrorLoadingDll

Works fine in command prompt,but when triggered from jenkins says access violation reading error